# Changing character speed in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a "FirstPersonController" that I have renamed "Player". I want to set the variable in the Player:

```
Character Motor -> Movement -> Max Forward Speed
```

I have tried searching how to do this, and the closest I have come is this:

```
var player : CharacterMotor;
player.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 12;
```

error:

```
'movement' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.
```

What I'm looking for is what is the easiest way of changing this value?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the variable `player` with `GetComponent(CharacterMotor);` and then change the `maxForwardSpeed`. Something like this:

```
player = GetComponent(CharacterMotor);
player.movement.maxForwardSpeed = 12;
```